# Import class from upper directory into python script

Tags: python

I would like to import the `Tokenizer` class located in `tokenizer.py` script into `generate_vocab.py` script. Here's my tree view:

```
 - bin
   - tokenizer
     - tokenizer.py
   - tools
     - generate_vocab.py
```

What I would like to do is to call something like: `from ../tokenizer import tokenizer.py`.

Do I need to use a `__init__.py` script to make my `bin/tokenizer` directory a module and then call `from ... import tokenizer` ?

Comment: have yout tried from ..tokenizer import tokenizer?

Comment: yes plug in a `__init__.py` and  try `from ../tokenizer import tokenizer`, that should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder

Comment: @MarvinTaschenberger When I try `from ..tokenizer import tokenizer` I get `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` Do I need a `__init__.py` script inside my `tools` directory as well ?